# DateTime.AddMilliSeconds doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, gps

I've got a simple function to take an `int` representing GPS week, and a double representing GPS seconds. The `GPS Week` is the number of weeks since midnight on 6th January 1980, and the  `GPS seconds` are the number of seconds since the last GPS week started. I want to turn these into a string with a particular format so that I can match GPS data with data from another instrument.

My function is as follows:

```
private DateTime GetFromGps(int weeknumber, double seconds)
    {
        DateTime datum = new DateTime(1980, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0);
        DateTime week = datum.AddDays(weeknumber * 7);
        DateTime time = week.AddSeconds(Math.Floor(seconds));
        double millisecs = (seconds - Math.Floor(seconds)) * 1000;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", seconds, Math.Floor(seconds), (int)millisecs);
        time.AddMilliseconds((int)millisecs);
        Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd,HH:mm:ss.fff"));
        return time;
    }
```

Now when `weeknumber = 1254` and `seconds = 412250.000` I get correct output of:

```
412250, 412250, 0
2004.01.22,18:30:50.000
```

However, when I use `weeknumber = 1254` and `seconds = 412250.123` the output looks like this:

```
412250.123, 412250, 123
2004.01.22,18:30:50.000
```

I've also tried without casting milliseconds to `int` and still had the same problem. I'd really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: DateTimes are immutable...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmilliseconds(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks @Tyler, that's sorted it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not storing the result of the `AddMilliseconds()` call. You need to say

```
DateTime newTime = time.AddMilliseconds(millisecs);
Console.WriteLine(newTime.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd,HH:mm:ss.fff"));
```